# User-chosen word in a variable (bash)

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

In a bash script I have variable with a list of PDF files, say
`list="a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf"`.
The list should be presented as a numbered list to the user:

```
    Available files are:
    1. a.pdf
    2. b.pdf
    3. c.pdf
    Please choose a file to be viewed or exit (defaul 1, exit 0)
```

Then, according to the user input the relevant action should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read`](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html) to get the input and use a for loop to iterate the items. You will probably need to split the the string into multiple objects. If you already got an array try to use it.

Further information: [Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash)